# Parse a formatted string -- isolate quoted substring and curly braced UUID

Tags: php, scanf, uuid, text-parsing

I am trying to parse a list of operating system instances with their unique identifiers. I am looking for a solution to parse a text string, and pass the values into two variables. The string to be parsed is as followed:

```
"Ubuntu 9.10" {40f2324d-a6b2-44e4-90c3-0c5fa82c987d}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for an excuse to read the docs for [sscanf()](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
sscanf($s, '"%[^"]" {%[^}]}', $os, $ident);
echo $os, "<br>", $ident;
```

**Followup:** For interest's sake, out of the three answers currently on this question:

```
sscanf: 0.92999792098999 seconds
preg_match: 4.73761510849 seconds
str_replace x2 + preg_split: 3.7644839286804 seconds
```

[Benchmark here](http://603.be/cHUzZx). Funny that two `str_replace()` and a `preg_split()` are faster than the `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to match the groups you need:

```
$str = '"Ubuntu 9.10" {40f2324d-a6b2-44e4-90c3-0c5fa82c987d}';
preg_match('/^"(.*)" {(.*)}$/', $str, $matches);
```

You can make the regular expression narrower based on the values (e.g. the second `.*` could be `[0-9a-f-]+`), but that's sufficient. `$matches[1]` will be "Ubuntu 9.10", and `$matches[2]` will be "40f2324d-a6b2-44e4-90c3-0c5fa82c987d"

Comment: +1 for use of regex capture groups; though the second `.*` would need to be `[0-9a-f\-]`, no? :)

Comment: @JYelton Ah, yes, although the escape isn't technically necessary. Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

This gets the two strings as first and second elements of a string array using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$s = "\"Ubuntu 9.10\" {40f2324d-a6b2-44e4-90c3-0c5fa82c987d}";
$s = str_replace("\" ", "|", $s); // substitute middle quotation mark and space for a delimiter
$s = str_replace("\"", "", $s); // remove quotation marks
$vars = preg_split('/\|/', $s); // split by delimiter
print_r($vars);
```

Comment: `explode()` is faster than `preg_split()` given a single-character delimiter.