# How to parse string with php?

Tags: php

I try to parse string with php using `sscanf()`:

```
$n = sscanf($line, "%s.%s.%s=%s", $ws, $layer, $perm, $role);
echo $ws." - ".$layer." - ".$perm." - ".$role."\n";
```

And get output:

```
*.*.r=* -  -  -
topp.*.a=jdbs_watcher -  -  -
```

Input examples:

```
 *.*.r=*
 topp.*.a=jdbs_watcher
```

What i expect to see for second string:

```
topp - * - a - jdbc_watcher
```

Why whole string has been put into `$ws` variable?

Comment: You might want to tell us what is your expected output

Comment: Need more info what you want to achive, but I would do it with exlode() and concatenatios after.

Comment: I update question please look at it.

Comment: I post an answer, use `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `^` to avoid to be too greedy:

```
<?php
$line = 'topp.*.a=jdbs_watcher';
$n = sscanf($line, "%[^.].%[^.].%[^=]=%s", $ws, $layer, $perm, $role);
echo $ws." - ".$layer." - ".$perm." - ".$role."\n";
```

Comment: `"%[^.].%[^.].%[^=]=%s"` looks like a hell.

Answer (score 3):

`%s` will match as many characters as it can before a whitespace delimiter. You could get something similar working with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead:

```
preg_match("/(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)=(.*)/", $line, $matches);
array_shift($matches);
list($ws, $layer, $perm, $role) = $matches;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks its what i need. i tried to use sscanf() becouse there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917886/php-string-parsing says that its work faster that another functions.

Comment: is this the same: '(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(.*?)=(.*)' ?

Comment: @lvil That is not quite the same, but it is the same if there are exactly two `.`  dots before the first `=` in the string. If there are more, than yours will be a non-greedy version, so `$ws` will contain as many `.`s as it can, for `$layer` and `$perm` to still exist.

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf()` is not a string parser. It is a formatted input scanner, which is used to assign formatted input into variables using C-style syntax. What you want to accomplish can be done with `explode()`.

```
//Scan input
$n = sscanf($line, "%s", $input);

//Parse by .
$parsed = explode(".", $input);
//Parse by =
$parsed[2] = explode("=", $parsed[2]);

//Create bindings
$ws = $parsed[0];
$layer = $parsed[1];
$perm = $parsed[2][0];
$role = $parsed[2][1];

//Echo
echo $ws." - ".$layer." - ".$perm." - ".$role."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there this behaviour was spotted before on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#81842).

As a workaround, you may use this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$line = 'topp.*.a=jdbs_watcher';

list($ws, $layer, $perm) = explode('.', $line);
list($perm, $role) = explode('=', $perm); 

echo $ws." - ".$layer." - ".$perm." - ".$role."\n";
?>
```

Result:

```
topp - * - a - jdbs_watcher
```